# Currency code returns nil

Tags: swift, swift3

A simple request for currency code as done below should return the currency code but it returns nil. Do I need set the region before requesting the currency code or is there something I am missing. I am using Swift 3.1 and Xcode 8.3.3 iphone 6 and same result on my simulator.

```
    if let currencyCode = Locale.current.currencyCode {
        print(currencyCode)
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kindly select the system language from edit scheme and then check
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I cannot think of a case when the currencyCode will not be returned, but as seen in the documentation, it is Optional. Could you please give more information about your specific locale?

A suggestion - print the currencySymbol instead and post the result here:

```
if let currencySymbol = Locale.current.currencySymbol {
    print(currencySymbol)
}
```

Comment: My current Locale if I understand your question is Denmark and the currencyCode should be DKK. The result from the print statement is Optional("¤")